# Starting an exe hidden from a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, exe

Basically, I need to start a program hidden (not minimized) and this needs to be done using a batch file with additional options (URL), is there any way to do this **without** the need of 3rd party add-ons?

*Edit:*
With "hidden", I mean that the file will not pop-up and cannot be seen in the taskbar (so the only sign of it working is in task manager)

Comment: What's *"hidden"* supposed to mean? In its current form, this question cannot be answered.

Comment: I mean hidden in a way where you do not see the executable window, and the only way to see if its active is to open the taskmanager

Comment: This should go into the question, not posted as a comment. Click the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37897559/edit) link to update your question.

Comment: Is your question answered or still open?

Comment: yes it is answered, thank you for the reminder. i have now accepted Maximilian Peters answer

Comment: Great! Glad it worked :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a VBScript which you can start any way you want.

Save this snippet as `test.vbs` and start it either from the command line or file explorer.

```
Set oShell = CreateObject ("Wscript.Shell") 
oShell.Run "notepad.exe", 0, true
```

This will start `notepad`, but without showing its window. You can still find it in the Task Manager. See here for a detailed [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky(VS.85).aspx).

---

**Update to comment**

Internet explorer is one of the programs which ignores the Window State set to 0 in the above script.

Work around: change your test.vbs file

```
Dim ie 
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = False
ie.Navigate "stackoverflow.com"
```

Change the URL to something you don't usually visit and you should see it in the IE history.

Documentation for

- [CreateObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752084(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Documentation for Navigate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752093(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Is there any way to launch for example IEXPLORE.exe with an URL?